# Can anyone explain javascript sort() function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

here I try to sort integer array like

**`var points = [000, 100, 010, 101, 001, 011, 110, 111];`**

using **`points.sort();`** but the output was *0,1,100,101,110,111,8,9*. I was really confused with that, and 8,9 comes from where.

Comment: Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: __Always__ take a look at the documentation first. Questions like this are easily answered with a glance at the specifications of the function.

Comment: @Bergi In fact not. See Daniel's good answer.

Comment: Oh, and don't "pad" your integers with leading zero's. That will give unexpected results.

Comment: @dystroy: Oh, right, because it's two questions. For the second, see [Why does 0154 === 108?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5000848/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8 is from 010, 9 is from 011, because they are interpreted as octal numbers

You need to remove the preceding zeros

And then you need to use the comparison function in sort() :

```
points.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b })
```

Comment: +1 because I hadn't noticed this second problem

Comment: thats fine,can u explain step by step execution of `points.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b })`  for the above example after removing preceding zero.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the default sorting is based on string comparison.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) :

> If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order

To sort numbers, do

```
points.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b })
```

EDIT : @Daniel pointed another problem, that is the fact your number literals aren't interpreted as you think they are, you should remove the non significant zeros.

Comment: True, but that's not the problem here.

Comment: @Cerbrus Actually it's half the problem